# Intellij does not seem to compile or interpret JavaScript properly, and any changes or settings on IntelliJ cannot be saved

Tags: javascript, android, html, react-native, intellij-idea

I'm currently learning React Native and JavaScript for a mobile application development. I have been in this problem for quite a while and wish to know what went wrong.
After having downloaded Expo and open the App.js through Intellij, I noticed that the code does not show any color for the important keywords, and that there isn't any meaningful suggestion for library or methods whenever I made changes on the JavaScript/HTML code. This makes me wonder, if JavaScript cannot be interpreted on IntelliJ or do I need to install any additional software for the compiler to do so.
[The App.js file when I opened it][1]

Moreover, whenever I made any changes to the code line, it does not allow me to save the code. At first, I tried to avoid the error message, but the changes cannot be viewed on my phone as well when I opened Expo. This is the error messages:
[Error shows that I cannot save the file][2]
[Unable to save settings][3]

Is there anything I can do to resolve these errors? Thank you!
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/AA4Uk.png
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/BdZEX.png
[3]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/41ncv.png

Comment: Try creating a project in a user directory, not in System32. The IDE probably doesn't have enough permissions there.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! I have resolved the issue of not being able to change the code by not running the app administratively. However, there is still the problem of IDE seems to not understand JavaScript. Do you have any suggestion on that?